# How to sniff a socket without using socat?

Tags: osx, usb, socket, socat

I would like to do socket sniffing, but I'm wondering what options there to do without using `socat`? I can't use that command, since it's not already installed (and I cannot install it). I thought network cat (`nc`) would do it, but it seems like it won't. I'm trying to do this on the terminal in OS X, but will need to do this on Redhat 7 at some point as well.

Comment: It would be useful to explain what protocol and whether it is encrypted or not.

Comment: It is unencrypted. And it's TCP. It should be a stream socket.

Comment: What app is generating that data? Email, sql, json, http?

Comment: I think usbmuxd. I'm more or less trying to follow what's happening here, but without the use of socat: https://medium.com/@jon.gabilondo.angulo_7635/understanding-usbmux-and-the-ios-lockdown-service-7f2a1dfd07ae

Comment: Would tcpdump work with the -d or -dd option?